How do I prevent two recipes from installing the same file in a bitbake?
I am trying to create an SDK using bitbake -c populate_sdk fsl-image-gui. I am doing this in a Docker Container built from Ubuntu 22.04. This is for Yocto Kirkstone. Two recipes in this bitbake are providing the same file. At the very end of the bake (at 99%, on the do_populate_sdk task), I get the error:
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4373.bin from install of linux-firmware-bcm4373-1:20221214-r0.noarch conflicts with file from package lwb5plus-usb-sa-firmware-11.171.0.24-r0.noarch

These two recipes are provided by Laird/Ezurio and by the Yocto project.
I have tried patching all mentions of bcm4373 out of the Yocto poky file, but I still get the error. What is the correct way to make sure that only one package installs this file? Is it PREFERRED_PROVIDER, ALTERNATIVES, or some secret third option?
I used a patch file to remove all mentions of bcm4373 from the Yocto-provided file. This is being applied using the patch command during the Docker container build, not through a .bbappend file. I hoped this would cause it to not install the problem file, but it still gives the same error, likely because there is some dependency on it.
